# @IpsEnumId removed by IPS-Generator, even though I annotated method with @customziedAnnotations ADDED

Tags: annotations, customization, faktor-ips

I'd like to annotate a getter-method with `@IpsEnumId(enumType = MyEnum.class)`.

As I know from [Annotations are removed by Faktor-IPS Code Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291931/annotations-are-removed-by-faktor-ips-code-generator), I tried to add a Java-Doc-Line `@customizedAnnotations ADDED`. But that does not work. My annotation line disappears after a rebuild.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

All annotations starting with `@Ips` are treated by the code generator as its own and are not affected by `@customizedAnnotations`. You can tell Faktor-IPS to always keep an annotation you manually added in the .ipsproject file with the line
`<Property name="retainAnnotations" value="IpsEnumId"/>`
in the `<IpsArtefactBuilderSetConfig>` section.